# Redirection of MySQL Queries into a log/text file in shell script and read the file for particular string

Tags: mysql, linux, shell

I have written a shell script `MySQL_Test.sh` to connect to the MySQL database from linux shell and execute three different select statements like the following, 
`Select count(*) as My_Column_Name from <table_name> where <condition>` 
 My shell script looks like the following.

```
mysql -u$MASTER_DB_USER -p$MASTER_DB_PASSWD -P$MASTER_DB_PORT -h$MASTER_DB_HOST <<EOF
$BS_Query 
$Exp_Query
$ROI_Query
EOF
```

Now my requirements are, 
1. I would like to redirect the output of the three above queries into a single text or log file.
2. Send an email if any of the query returns > 0 rows.
3. Attach the text/log file while sending the email. 
 
Could anyone please help me in fixing 1 and 2. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql -u$DB_USER -p$PASSWD -P$DB_PORT -h$DB_HOST <<EOF > output.txt
$BS_Query 
$Exp_Query
$ROI_Query
EOF

# For each even line (i.e. containing the count(*) result), test if count(*) != 0
line_number=1
for line in `cat output.txt`; do
  if [ $((line_number % 2)) -eq 0 ]; then
    if [ $line -ne 0 ]; then
      `( echo "Here is your report"; uuencode output.txt output.txt ) | mail -s "SQL report" admin@sqldb`
      exit
    fi
  fi
  line_number=$((line_number + 1))
done
```

Comment: Hi Sylvain... Thank you verymuch for this... It worked for me... Can we attach the output.txt to the mail as well in the same line???

Comment: You said you wanted only 1 and 2 :). To attach the generated file, you can use: `( echo "Here is your report"; uuencode output.txt output.txt ) | mail -s "SQL report" admin@sqldb`. More explanations [here](http://www.shelldorado.com/articles/mailattachments.html)

Comment: I've edited my answer with this command to have a complete script.